# Redux add object to array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have the following problem...

I want to add an object to an array of objects using redux in my react-native application.
I get this error message:

Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

```
// my action

export function newTaskAction(){
  return{
    type: ADD_NEW_TASK,
    payload: {
      new: { id: '5', task:'test123'}
    }
  }
}



//my reducer

export default function taskReducer(state = initialUserState, action){
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case ADD_NEW_TASK :
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: [...state.tasks, payload.new]
            }
        default:
            return state
    }




const store = createStore(allReducers, {
 tasks: [
   {id: "1", task: "React Native lernen"},
   {id: "2", task: "Redux lernen"},
   {id: "3", task: "Etwas lesen"},
   {id: "4", task: "Einkaufen gehen"}
 ],
 user: 'Frank'
});
```

Comment: what does state.tasks holdes?

Comment: I added the current state to my question

Comment: How did you resolve it? @maximus26

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
[...state.tasks, payload.new]
```

to

```
tasks: [...state.tasks, action.payload.new]
```

Comment: payload: {
      new: { id: '5', task:'test123'}
    } .   
change it to :  payload:{ id: '5', task:'test123'} @maximus26

Comment: unfortunately no change

Comment: you should remove `new` after the previous change from `tasks: [...state.tasks, action.payload.new]`. it will be `tasks: [...state.tasks, action.payload]` at the end. If returns error, tell us what error this is.

Comment: it still says Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it supposed to be?

`return {
     ...state,
     tasks: [...state.tasks, action.payload.new]
}`

missing `action`

Comment: @maximus26 check your `initialUserState` , probably something wrong in there

Comment: its just an empty array...tasks:[]

Comment: @maximus26 try putting console log and check `action` and `store` objects in the reducer. their content should show what's possibly wrong

Comment: try this: 
`return console.log(action) || {
                ...state,
                tasks: [...state.tasks, action.payload.new]
            }`

Comment: and please check if your other reducers are working well. if you have same problem all over the application, then it's probably related to middleware configuration lines.

Comment: the console log shows an object with the type und the payload object... my other reducer works fine... it contains just a string

Comment: the `initialUserState` , is it tasks inside an object, or just task: [] ?

Comment: it's inside an object

Comment: @maximus26 not sure if you tried, but would u console log `state.tasks` the same way you did action?

Answer (score 0):

Please use Object.assign

```
 case Actions.CART_ADD_ITEM: 
        return Object.assign({}, state, { tasks: [...state.tasks,  { id: '5', task:'test123'}] });
```

Please use the task list in View like this

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
tasksList: state.tasksReducer.tasks} 
);


<FlatList
    data={this.props.tasksList}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your initial state, if you have defined tasks: null, then when you try to do a spread operator on [ ...state.tasks ] it will throw an error because it is null. Instead define tasks: []. You didn't post that as part of your code examples, so only guessing based on when I've had that same error.